# Start a Query Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, php

Is there any sample code available that would show how to run an existing query activity via the SOAP api in php? There is a .net example on @Code but I'm not entirely sure of how to translate that to php.

Thanks!
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Creating a Query Activity](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_query_activity/) There is both a .Net and a PHP example there.

Comment: Thanks. I have created the Query Activity already and the query is available through the account UI, I'm just trying to figure out how to start it through the API. Similar to this: https://code.exacttarget.com/question/run-query-activity-php

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample 'Perform a Query Activity Using the SOAP Web Service API' here:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api/